# Relation on partitions having $1$ as summand

Tags: group-theory

If $p_1(n)$ is the number of partitions of n having $1$ as a summand, then $p_1(n) = p(n − 1)$ for $n ≥ 2,$
for all such partitions of n can be obtained by putting $+1$ after each partition of $n − 1$. Thus for
$n ≥ 2, p(n) =$(number of partitions without $1$ as a summand)$ + p(n − 1)$

$5 = 5 = 2 + 3 \therefore p(5) = 2 + p(4) = 2 + 5 = 7$

$6 = 6 = 2 + 4 = 3 + 3 = 2 + 2 + 2 \therefore p(6) = 4 + p(5) = 4 + 7 = 11$

Comment: What part of it is ambiguous for you exactly?

Comment: I couldn't follow the reasoning because of use of language. if someone paraphrases it, I would really appreciate

Comment: I tried my best to rephrase it for you. Does it help? There are two possibilities when you partition $n$. Either you partition it in a way that a summand of $1$ occurs, or you partition it in a way that no summand of $1$ occurs. Since they're disjoint possibilities, the numbers of ways that you can partition $n$ is equal to the sum of the number of ways for doing each. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p_1(n)$ represents the number of partitions of $n$ such that for some number $m$, we have $n=m+1$.  Therefore, our problem has been reduced to the number of ways we can partition $m$. But $m=n-1$. Therefore, $p_1(n)=p(m)=p(n-1)$

Now, suppose that $n\geq 2$ and $p(n)$ is the number of ways we have partitioned $n$.

$$\{\text{ways we can partition n}\}=$$
$$\{\text{ways we can partition $n$ without 1 as a summand}\} \cup \{\text{ways we can partition $n$ with 1 as a summand}\}$$

Since the two sets are disjoint, their numbers add up. Also, since the last set by definition is $p_1(n)$, and we already showed that $p_1(n)=p(n-1)$, you get the claim of the book.

In a more verbose fashion,

There are two possibilities when you partition $n$. Either you partition it in a way that a summand of $1$ occurs, or you partition it in a way that no summand of $1$ occurs. Since the two possibilities contradict each other, the numbers of ways that you can partition $n$ is equal to the sum of the number of ways for each possibility.

Comment: What about computation? Let's say for $n =5$

Comment: For example, for the first one, the only ways you can partition $5$ without $1$ as a summand is $5$ and $2+3$ . Therefore, $p(5)=2+p(4)$. Do you get it now? Same thing for the other one. The only ways that $6$ can be partitioned without $1$ as a summand are $6$, $4+2$, $3+3$, $2+2+2$. Therefore, $p(6)=4+p(5)$